# line breaks appearing in sourcecode after mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

I am doing a simple query to retrieve car manufacturers from my db:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT model_make_display_name FROM car_query_models_full ORDER By model_make_display_name ASC") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<p>".$row['model_make_display_name']."</p>\n";
}
```

The data is appearing as normal in HTML view, however when I view source some of the results are appearing like so:

```
<p>Ariel
</p>
<p>Armstrong </p>
<p>Ascari
</p>
<p>Aston Mart</p>
<p>Audi
</p>
<p>Austin
</p>
<p>Austin Hea</p>
<p>Autobianch</p>
<p>Auverland
</p>
<p>Avanti
</p>
<p>Beijing
</p>
<p>Bentley
</p>
```

Notice some of the names are adding a break after the text forcing the closing p tag to go onto next line, what could be causing this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked for newline characters on the ends of those manufacturers? Try

```
echo "<p>".trim($row['model_make_display_name'])."</p>\n";
```

to see if they're present. If so, simply cleanse the database (on entry or one-time) and you'll be good to go.

Comment: there are no newline characters on the ends of any manufacturers :S but that trim function worked and the output looks fine in the source code, does that indicate that I still need to cleanse the db? if so how?, there are 55,000+ rows

Comment: I'd guess you got some kind of funky/obscure whitespace character on data entry somehow. You could go through and do an UPDATE query for each one with the trim($row['model_make_display_name']) for the new value, or if it's not too intense on your app you could just leave it with the trim. Play it by ear depending on where and how you're using it...

Comment: FYI this worked a treat:

UPDATE car_query_models_full SET model_make_display_name = TRIM( "\r" FROM model_make_display_name );

Answer (score 1):

The way it's stored in the database is causing this.

You can try:

```
echo "<p>" . htmlspecialchars( $row['model_make_display_name'] ) . "</p>\n";
```

Or replace `\n` and `\r` from the value:

```
SELECT ... REPLACE(model_make_display_name, '\n', '')
```

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).